# Enterprise App Distribution from Iphone to Iphone via WIFI (No Web server, no local network)

Tags: ios, iphone

I have noticed that there are walkie-talkie apps that communicate between 2 Iphones via WIFI.
Each Iphone searches for an available Iphone with the Walkie-talkie App. If this works then there must be a way to distribute an Enterprise App within the reach of the Sending Iphone`s WIFI to a second Iphone with it`s WIFI turn on and no app on board.

How it could happen:
Step 1 - First Iphone searches for Iphone within WIFI range.
Step 2 - Push Notification of Available App.
Step 3 - Second Iphone responds affirmative to request, asking for App.
Step 4 - First Iphone pushes .plist and .ipa files to second Iphone with install prompt.
Step 5 - Second Iphone installs app.

There of course could other features.

Can this be done?

Sometimes you have an App on your phone and meet someone who wants your app but they can`t download it at that moment because the WIFI and Cellular networks are too slow where you are located. Many times the app is never downloaded by this person and the opportunity is lost. I have experienced this many times. Wouldn`t this App above be a good solution for this problem. You could also add a feature in the downloaded app to in the future download the App Store version which is available.

If you know how to do this would you give your input? Thanks for your help, James Vernon

Answer (score 1):

At least for an enterprise app this seems feasible. While there's no mechanism available to push a .ipa onto a device there are over the air installs which have been in use for years. (For example I used them to distribute as hoc builds from a continuous integration server: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/05/04/automated-ad-hoc-builds-using-xcode-4/)

If the host device can run a web server to serve te .ipa and a .plist then the client device just needs to visit the appropriate URL to fetch the app.

Of course this assumes that you are willing to allow enterprise app distribution out of your control. I'm not sure if that complies with the enterprise license agreements. It also depends on the wifi network in use allowing peer to peer traffic which is not always the case.

I don't know that the end result is useful to anyone but some parts of what you describe seem feasible.

Comment: Thanks for giving your input, Jonah